# Django blog - calling latest 3 posts per category via many to many

Tags: python, django, django-views

So far my blog project has :

> Models.py

```
 class Category(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "categories"


class Post(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        summary = models.CharField(max_length=500, default = True)
        body = models.TextField()
        pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
        categories = models.ForeignKey('Category', default=True)


        def __str__(self):
            return self.title
```

> Views

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Post, Category

def getAllCategories(request):
    categories = Category.objects.all()

    context = {
        'categories':categories,
            }

    return render(request, 'categories/getAllCategories.html', context)
```

> Template

```
 {% extends "../posts/base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <div>
        {% for category in categories %}
            <div>
                <h3>{{ category.title }}</h3>
                <ul>
                {% for post in category.post_set.all %}
                    <li><a href=#>{{post.title}}</a></li> 
                        - {{post.summary}}
                {% endfor %}
                </ul>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

This pulls through all of my posts per category fine - however I'm stuck as I would like to only pull through the latest three posts per category. I understand that in a simple view you can use order_by()[:3], but then you can't use post_set with that. So I need a way of filtering by top three posts within a category, so using the many-to-many relationship. Hope this is clear.

Many thanks

Comment: You *can* use `post_set` with that.

Comment: You can use |slice:":3" after post_set.all

Comment: Awesome - thanks! I couldn't use post_set in the view though - how would I re-write the view to include a post_set  and order by? Would they need to be separate variables?

Comment: You can query your post: Post.objects.filter(categeory="string").order_by("categories"),